# How do I keep values when using 'extract' to split strings in adresses?

Tags: r, string, split, extract

```
street              housenumber
wallstreet 17-20    NULL
wafflestreet        5
```

```
extract("street", c("street", "housnumber"), "(\\D+)(\\d.*)"
```

*output*

```
street         housenumber
wallstreet     17-20
NA             NA
```

**How do I not get NAs? How do I keep `wafflestreet` and its `housenumber`?**

Comment: Please post the input data in `dput(head(input_data))` format. (Post the output of that R instruction.)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can try the code below

```
df %>%
  separate_wider_delim(street, delim = " ", names = c("street", "housenum"), too_few = "align_start") %>%
  mutate(housenum = coalesce(housenum, housenumber)) %>%
  select(-housenumber)
```

or

```
df %>%
  separate_wider_regex(street, patterns = c(street = "\\S+", " ", housenum = "\\S+"), too_few = "align_start") %>%
  mutate(housenum = coalesce(housenum, housenumber)) %>%
  select(-housenumber)
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  street       housenum
  <chr>        <chr>
1 wallstreet   17-20
2 wafflestreet 5
```

## Data

```
df <- data.frame(
  street = c("wallstreet 17-20", "wafflestreet"),
  housenumber = c(NA, "5")
)
```

Comment: Thank you @ThomasIsCoding ! I also came up with this solution meanwhile:

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>%
mutate(housenum = ifelse(str_detect(street,"(\\d.*)"),
       str_extract(street,"(\\d.*)"),housenum),
       street = str_remove(street,'\\d.*'))
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**